# Multi threaded object creation slower then in a single thread

Tags: java, multithreading

I have what probably is a basic question. When I create 100 million Hashtables it takes approximately 6 seconds (runtime = 6 seconds per core) on my machine if I do it on a single core. If I do this multi-threaded on 12 cores (my machine has 6 cores that allow hyperthreading) it takes around 10 seconds (runtime = 112 seconds per core).

This is the code I use:

**Main**

```
public class Tests 
{
public static void main(String args[])
{
    double start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    int nThreads = 12;
    double[] runTime = new double[nThreads];

    TestsThread[] threads = new TestsThread[nThreads];
    int totalJob = 100000000;
    int jobsize = totalJob/nThreads;
    for(int i = 0; i < threads.length; i++)
    {
        threads[i] = new TestsThread(jobsize,runTime, i);
        threads[i].start();
    }
    waitThreads(threads);
    for(int i = 0; i < runTime.length; i++)
    {
        System.out.println("Runtime thread:" + i + " = " + (runTime[i]/1000000) + "ms");
    }
    double end = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println("Total runtime = " + (end-start) + " ms");
}

private static void waitThreads(TestsThread[] threads) 
{
    for(int i = 0; i < threads.length; i++)
    {
        while(threads[i].finished == false)//keep waiting untill the thread is done
        {
            //System.out.println("waiting on thread:" + i);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }   
}
}
```

**Thread**

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class TestsThread extends Thread
{
int jobSize = 0;
double[] runTime;
boolean finished;
int threadNumber;

TestsThread(int job, double[] runTime, int threadNumber)
{
    this.finished = false;
    this.jobSize = job;
    this.runTime = runTime;
    this.threadNumber = threadNumber;
}

public void run()
{
    double start = System.nanoTime();
    for(int l = 0; l < jobSize ; l++)
    {   
         double[] test = new double[65];
    }
    double end = System.nanoTime();
    double difference = end-start;
    runTime[threadNumber] += difference;
    this.finished = true;
}
}
```

I do not understand why creating the object simultaneously in multiple threads takes longer per thread then doing it in serial in only 1 thread. If I remove the  line where I create the Hashtable this problem disappears. If anyone could help me with this I would be greatly thankful.

Comment: I'd say creating 100,000,000 hashtables is the problem.

Comment: Is the application actually using multiple cores?  I could see it taking longer if it was not spanning cores and had to flop out the threads because then you would have that overhead.

Comment: And when you remove the hashtable creation your threads are doing nothing, so there is nothing to compare ;0

Comment: Your usage of the `runtime` variable kinda scares me.

Comment: @Bobby It should scare you because it is involved in a data race. All readouts from that kind of code are worthless.

Comment: @Sipko, you need to synchronize. The loop for runtime can fire and finish, before any hashtable creation happens(potentially). or any amount of them

Comment: Wanted to test this, but timer seems to be some custom class, since java.util.Timer and swing Timer have no getTime methods. Maybe timer is problem here!?

Comment: Also there might be problem with your `endThreads(threads);` method. Please provide SSCCE http://sscce.org/ for more help

Comment: I have reworked the code a bit so it resolves most of the issues raised before. It should be easy to copy paste the code if you feel like giving this a try.

Answer (score 1):

Update: This problem has an associated [bug report](http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=8006593) and has been fixed with `Java 1.7u40`. And it was never an issue for `Java 1.8` as Java 8 has an entirely different hash table algorithm.

---

Since you are not using the created objects that operation will get optimized away. So you’re only measuring the overhead of creating threads. This is surely the more overhead the more threads you start.

I have to correct my answer regarding a detail, I didn’t know yet: there is something special with the classes `Hashtable` and `HashMap`. They both invoke `sun.misc.Hashing.randomHashSeed(this)` in the constructor. In other words, their instances escape during construction which has an impact on the memory visibility. This implies that their construction, unlike let’s say for an `ArrayList`, cannot optimized away, and multi-threaded construction slows down due to what happens inside that method (i.e. synchronization).

As said, that’s special to these classes and of course this implementation (my setup:`1.7.0_13`). For ordinary classes the construction time goes straight to zero for such code.

Here I add a more sophisticated benchmark code. Watch the difference between `DO_HASH_MAP = true` and `DO_HASH_MAP = false` (when `false` it will create an `ArrayList` instead which has no such special behavior).

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.concurrent.*;

public class AllocBench {
  static final int NUM_THREADS = 1;
  static final int NUM_OBJECTS = 100000000 / NUM_THREADS;
  static final boolean DO_HASH_MAP = true;

  public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
    ExecutorService threadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(NUM_THREADS);
    Callable<Long> task=new Callable<Long>() {
      public Long call() {
        return doAllocation(NUM_OBJECTS);
      }
    };

    long startTime=System.nanoTime(), cpuTime=0;
    for(Future<Long> f: threadPool.invokeAll(Collections.nCopies(NUM_THREADS, task))) {
      cpuTime+=f.get();
    }
    long time=System.nanoTime()-startTime;
    System.out.println("Number of threads: "+NUM_THREADS);
    System.out.printf("entire allocation required %.03f s%n", time*1e-9);
    System.out.printf("time x numThreads %.03f s%n", time*1e-9*NUM_THREADS);
    System.out.printf("real accumulated cpu time %.03f s%n", cpuTime*1e-9);

    threadPool.shutdown();
  }

  static long doAllocation(int numObjects) {
    long t0=System.nanoTime();
    for(int i=0; i<numObjects; i++)
      if(DO_HASH_MAP) new HashMap<Object, Object>(); else new ArrayList<Object>();
    return System.nanoTime()-t0;
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm nearly sure that creation and starting of 12 empty threads will not take 10 seconds.

Comment: No, it will not get optimized away. You are making empty claims here.

Comment: On a system that needs 6 seconds for a single thread it will be. I’d rather question the entire measuring process. I don’t know what that timer using `double`does.

Comment: Not to mention the unsynchronized access to the same array entry.

Comment: @Holger: It is kinda stupid. OP creates an Array of doubles with only one entry, because Arrays are passed by reference, so OP basically "invented" a pass-by-reference-double which is absolutely not thread-safe.

Comment: @Marko Topolnik: it depends on the JVM and several environmental conditions so you can’t rely on it. However the overhead of creating a local object that is never used is far smaller than that of creating a new thread.

Comment: One thing which definitely does *not* figure in the timing is the overhead of thread creation. The overhead of thread *scheduling*, yes.

Comment: @Marko Topolnik just try it out. The question whether an object is really used makes a huge performance difference at least on a server JVM. And since a constructor is just a method with a special name to the JVM (which is invoke non-virtual) constructors are inlined like normal methods and optimized away if they don’t have an effect just like normal methods.

Comment: If I take out the "Hashtable<String,Integer> test = new Hashtable<String,Integer>();" line, the problem disappears and the program finsishes in less then 1 second. Therefore I think creating the threads is not the issue.

Comment: Concerning the unsynchronized acces to the same array. I know I am not supposed to do this, but just for the sake of keeping the post shorter and not having people argue the synchronization causes the delay I did it the "quick and dirty" way.

Comment: @Sipko in the case the allocation is not optimized away your constantly creation of objects will trigger the garbage collector which might have global impact, so your threads interfere with each other.

Comment: @Holger I think you might be right, but do you know a way to avoid this problem? I assumed there are more programs out there that create many objects inside different threads, that must somehow deal with this issue.

Comment: There are programs creating many objects, also inside different threads, but there are not much programs creating that large numbers of `Hashtable`s.

Comment: @Holger The origin of the problem is another far more elaborate script I wrote where it seems creating objects takes more time in multiple threads. These are different type of objects and depending on the size of the object the problem is bigger or smaller...

Comment: If the objects are really used, they will remain alive and using memory on the heap. That has an impact on all threads. But that’s a completely different question.

Comment: As you saw yourself, for `HashMap` there's no difference whether you use it or not. Neither is there for this simple class: `class A { final int[] x = {1}; public int hashCode() {return 0;} }`. This: `for (int i = 0; i < 1_000_000; i++) new A();` and this: `for (int i = 0; i < 1_000_000; i++) {
      A a = new A();
      a.hashCode();
    }` have almost exactly the same speed: 25 ops/msec, as measured with `jmh`. There *is* a difference for `ArrayList`, so maybe you've just found one of a few special cases which JVM feels confident enough to optimize away?

Comment: @Marko Topolnik: You are drawing the wrong conclusions. It makes no difference in your example whether you call hashCode or not because you aren’t using the result of you hashCode either. So that’s optimized away together with the allocation.

Comment: @Holger Then explain the difference between `new ArayList()`, which doesn't depend on the number of iterations---clearly optimized away, and `new A()`, which does scale with the number of iterations.

Comment: @Marko Topolnik: I don’t see any difference. On my machine. With my setup. Iterating 100 million times instead of one. Takes the same time as 200 millions. “25 ops/msec” is not a unit of time, by the way.

Comment: *If* you ever experience the situation that the JVM refuses to inline your code in your real application in a real scenario your welcome to start a new question and I’d love to help you solving this.

Comment: But the discussion about your artificial benchmarks showing what you want them to show is worthless. I have already corrected by answer regarding the original question. And surly, the original code starting new threads while the first one are already running will measure threading overhead. If the measuring was ever trustworthy. EOT.

Comment: @Sipko: the solution is to update to a recent Java implementation (I updated my answer). If you need a work-around for older versions, [this article](http://java-performance.info/changes-to-string-java-1-7-0_06/) offers a hack.

Answer (score 0):

What about if you do it on 6 cores? Hyperthreading isn't the exact same as having double the cores, so you might want to try the amount of real cores too.

Also the OS won't necessarily schedule each of your threads to their own cores.

Comment: If I run it on 6 cores I  have the same problem. Basically the problem scales with the number of cores I use.

Comment: On 2 threads it will run faster in total but the time spent per thread is longer.

Answer (score 0):

Since all you are doing is measuring the time and churning memory, your bottleneck is likely to be in your L3 cache or bus to main memory.  In this cases, coordinating the work between threads could be producing so much overhead it is worse instead of better.

This is too long for a comment but your inner loop can be just

```
double start = System.nanoTime();
for(int l = 0; l < jobSize ; l++){
    Map<String,Integer> test = new HashMap<String,Integer>();
}
// runtime is an AtomicLong for thread safety
runtime.addAndGet(System.nanoTime() - start); // time in nano-seconds.
```

Taking the time can be as slow creating a HashMap so you might not be measuring what you think you if you call the timer too often.

BTW Hashtable is synchronized and you might find using HashMap is faster, and possibly more scalable.

Comment: If the Hashtables are not used by multiple threads it should not make a difference if they are synchronized or not right? (I apologize if that is a stupid question but do not have an informatics background) I changed the code into creating HashMap objects instead (I edited my initial post), but the problem remains. Also I take the time outside the loop now to make sure measuring the time is not the issue. Thank you for those suggestions.

Comment: @Sipko The overhead of synchronization is smaller if there is no contention but it’s still there. The JVM might even optimize away that overhead if it can prove that an object is never seen by other threads. However, if there is an alternative that does not have that overhead in the first place, why not use it.

Comment: @Holger Thanks for the explanation. Using this suggestion however does not resolve the issue. I noticed if I replace the "Map<String,Integer> test = new HashMap<String,Integer>();" line with "double[] test = new double[65]" I get the same issue, however when I use "double[] test = new double[64]" it runs as expected.