# Why the array classes do not have any utility methods?

Tags: java, arrays

Why in Java programming language array is not made like a regular class, e.g. it can't be inherited from and it doesn't have any utility methods directly in its class (e.g. like a `String`)?

There are many methods that can be designed for arrays, e.g. 
`swap()`, searching methods, sorting methods, split/splice methods etc.

Comment: [Arrays are objects (§4.3.1), are dynamically created, and may be assigned to variables of type Object (§4.3.2)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-10.html)

Comment: Those methods could also be written for a `Collection`.

Comment: @NoahLevy Then please [edit] your question and rephrase it to avoid confusion.

Comment: Anyway arrays can have different dimensions. How would you like `swap(1,2)` method work for two dimensional array `int[][]`? Should such array even have such `swap` method? Should it swap rows or elements?

Comment: @Pshemo each array dimension should have its own methods, if int[] has sortMin then int[][] should have sortMinTopToBot or something like that, and all the searching methods are different for each dimension

Comment: Now the Question is opinion-based.  And moot.  Java is the way it is because those were the language design choices made 20+ years ago.  We don't know real reasons why they were made.  Though, once you start on the slippery slop of adding "useful" methods to an `array` class, it is hard to know when to stop.

Comment: @Pshemo honestly, it *could* have been done (e.g. C# handles it by variadic methods AFAIR); the point is - *would the pros outweigh the cons?*

Comment: Erm ... why?  Surely, you only get performance issues if the methods are non-final.  Actually, maybe "complexity" is a plausible explanation.  Complexity for people learning / using the language AND implementing it.

Comment: I think we should reopen this question so that you can give a proper explanation.  I know that arrays have distinct opcodes, etc.  But why does that stop the standard method invocation opcodes from being applicable to arrays-with-methods?  I can see a problem with fields ... but maybe the solution would be to ban array subclasses from defining instance fields.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111288/discussion-between-vaxquis-and-stephen-c).

Answer (score 6):

## tl;dr

It's mostly for historical reasons.

---

Arrays are (and were) treated like a special data type from the very beginning, having e.g. [distinct VM opcodes that were intended to deal only with them](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_bytecode_instruction_listings) (note there are literally *tons* of opcodes for array handling!). It was mostly made that way so that the performance of the arrays would be near-native (and so that JNI could interact with them easily). The design choice here was that the need for fast/memory-efficient primitive/array data types was put before the need for a "beautiful" interface, and that thus neither primitives nor arrays can't be "real" objects for the sake of VM performance.

While the [Oak Language Specification](http://www.javaspecialists.eu/archive/files/OakSpec0.2.ps) (Oak being the direct Java ancestor) stating `Although arrays can be created with new, just as instances of classes are created, arrays are not currently objects.` is *ancient* (ca. 20 years old), it still shows the general idea of this performance-elegance tradeoff - the very idea that is reiterated with respect to contemporary Java about 15 years later in the Oracle's own [Arrays 2.0 talk](http://medianetwork.oracle.com/video/player/1785452137001), giving a nice insight as to why it is the way it is, and what can we expect of it in the nearest future. I'll highlight my five cents about that very *why*.

First and foremost, sometimes an array is much better as a "fake" object instead of a "real" one, e.g. [there are some cases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18810505/declaring-multiple-arrays-with-64-elements-1000-times-faster-than-declaring-arra) (local array with <= 64 elements) when arrays are simply *inlined* into method code (as with local variables). Making them a regular class would make those optimizations much harder. The downside, however, is that it precluded the "regular" class/object use - since having a "regular" class/object behaviour would require the runtime to handle all the things like e.g. virtual dispatch, object constructors, GC with composition graphs etc., incurring a runtime penalty (see the footnote for a commentary). Note that `String` doesn't have these issues, because it is, under the hood... just a syntactic-sugar-covered `char[]` wrapper class!

Also, note that you can't e.g. *just "sort"* an array - there are many sort algorithms that could've been used, so the array class *should've* been open (overloadable etc.), if those utilities were added at all. Even more - proper design of such an interface would be (and *is*, as seen in C#) very tricky (due to e.g. multidimensinal arrays, nullable vs non-null arrays, possible cyclic references etc.), which would probably complicate the matter even more. OTOH, changing it would probably break backwards compatibility - so the Java devs decided it's better to let it be the way it is. Not long ago we had [a bug with Java lib's own TimSort some time ago](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8072909) - if it were included in a `final` array class, it would actually prevent the programmer from fixing it in place by overriding the method!

There are, however, both the utility class `java.util.Arrays` (with all the common array utilities you may need) *and* thin wrapper classes allowing proper object-oriented access to arrays (e.g. `ArrayList`). You can even write one yourself, and give your `ArrayWrapper` anything your soul desires; being a programmer is sometimes more about *creating* tools than about *using* them.

---

<sub>Note: it *is* possible to achieve real-object-like behaviour on arrays by using e.g. a syntax-aware source preprocessor/lexer (in a way similar to how [Lombok](https://projectlombok.org/) works) or by patching the compiler, which would, in turn, rewrite the pseudo-calls on arrays to a valid static method, passing the array as parameter; e.g. given a definition similar to `@ArrayEx(Arrays.class) int[] array;` it would convert commands like `array.sort();` into `Arrays.sort(array);` - yet, paraphrasing Eric Lippert, *it's not there because nobody bothered to code it*. If you find yourself in dire need of it for whatever reason - just write the code and submit the patch to OpenJDK or even just publish it on GitHub... that's mostly how OSS works *chuckle*. [Project Valhalla](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Project_Valhalla_(Java_language)) brings some hope here, because it's at least tangentially related to this matter - you may say that having object-like primitive values is a good way to pave a road to real object-like arrays. The aforementioned [Arrays 2.0 talk](http://medianetwork.oracle.com/video/player/1785452137001) actually highlights current "fake" object behaviour as one of the downsides of current implementation, mentioning some of the things I stated above as either conscious dev choices, or possible opportunities and pitfalls. All in all, maybe those good folks at Oracle/OpenJDK actually *will* add them in some future Java extension, who knows...</sub>